# A good way to escape quotes in a database query string?

Tags: python, database, escaping, sql-injection

I've tried all manner of Python modules and they either escape too much or in the wrong way.
What's the best way you've found to escape quotes (", ') in Python?

Comment: In what context do you want the escaping? For python strings, or into a database?

Comment: It's a part of a Postgres database query.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If it's part of a Database query you should be able to use a [Parameterized SQL Statement](https://web.archive.org/web/20100813151305/http://python.projects.postgresql.org/docs/0.8/driver.html).

As well as escaping your quotes, this will deal with all special characters and will protect you from [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681583/sql-injection-on-insert).

Comment: +1: If you're escaping quotes in a database query, you're doing the SQL wrong.

Comment: Excellent, now I just need a copy of Python 3.0.

Comment: Why do you need Python 3.0 to use a parameterized SQL statement?  They exist in all releases and all Postgres Python interfaces.

Comment: There are other features I need to use in Python 3.0.

Comment: All Python 3.0 features are available in Python 2.6.  Use that.

Comment: @S.Lott Can you explain why? Would you have a link for a better/cleaner way to do it than escaping quotes?

Comment: Not everything can be parameterized. In particular if you are trying to dynamically construct a SQL query. Like dynamic table names, or dynamic operators, using `>` or `<` depending on a boolean. Or having different number of parameters.

Comment: Similarly you cannot parameterize the individual values of an IN (...) construct whose number of items may vary.  One could certainly restructure the query (etc.) but there are valid circumstances for building portions of SQL "by hand".  It's very reasonable then to ask how to correctly sanitize that input.

Answer (score 24):

Use `json.dumps`.

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps('a"bc')
"a\"bc"
```

Comment: This fails when Unicode characters are included in the string: `print json.dumps(u"£")` prints `"\u00a3"`

Comment: Aside from the issue above this works pretty well, but it's a very heavy solution for a problem that can be addressed more simply.

Answer (score 11):

The easy and standard way to escape strings, and convert other objects to programmatic form, is to use the built in `repr()` function.  It converts an object into the representation you would need to enter it with manual code.

E.g.:

```
s = "I'm happy I am \"here\" now"
print repr(s)
>>  'I\'m happy I am "here" now'
```

No weird hacks, it's built in and it just works for most purposes.

Comment: This is probably not what the OP wants. repr does escapes the quotes but it also wraps the string in single quotes. For example: repr("King's Castle") becomes '"King\'s Castle"' (notice the wrapping quotes).

Comment: I end up with `u'I\'m happy I am "here" now'`.

Comment: `repr` escapes using Python rules, with backslashes.  My impression is OP wants to return an SQL literal which has different rules — single quotes should be doubled, backslashes not significant.

Answer (score 5):

If using psycopg2, its `execute()` method has built-in escaping:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT column FROM table WHERE column=%s AND column2=%s", (value1, value2))
```

Note, that you are giving two arguments to execute method (string and tuple), instead of using Python's % operator to modify string.

Answer stolen from here: [psycopg2 equivalent of mysqldb.escape_string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823735/psycopg2-equivalent-of-mysqldb-escape-string)

Answer (score 5):

Triple single quotes will conveniently encapsulate the single quotes often used in SQL queries:

```
c.execute('''SELECT sval FROM sdat WHERE instime > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 days' ORDER BY instime ASC''')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using psycopg2 that has a method for escaping strings: **`psycopg2.extensions.adapt()`** See [How to quote a string value explicitly (Python DB API/Psycopg2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309945/how-to-quote-a-string-value-explicitly-python-db-api-psycopg2) for the full answer

Answer (score 0):

For a solution to a more generic problem, I have a program where I needed to store *any* set of characters in a flat file, tab delimited. Obviously, having tabs in the 'set' was causing problems.

Instead of output_f.write(str), I used output_f.write(repr(str)), which solved my problem.
It is slower to read, as I need to eval() the input when I read it, but overall, it makes the code cleaner because I don't need to check for fringe cases anymore.

Comment: repr/eval is a bad idea in this case. You could use `csv` module instead. It will take care of embed tabs in the field for you

Answer (score 0):

Triple-double quotes are best for escaping:

```
string = """This will span across 'single quotes', "double quotes",
and literal EOLs all in the same string."""
```

Comment: It won't work in this case:
`string = """This is a string "containing a quote""""`

Answer (score -1):

For my use case, I was saving a paragraph against the database and somewhere in the paragraph there might have been some text with a single quote `(example: Charlie's apple sauce was soggy)`

I found this to work best:

```
database_cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO books.collection (book_name, book_quoted_text) VALUES ('%s', "%s")''' % (book_name, page_text.strip()))
```

You'll notice that I use `""` after wrapping the INSERT statement in `'''`