# python save sql INSERT statements to file . singlequotes around values colliding with single quotes present in the value being inserted

Tags: python, sql

I am using python to save a blogdata as an sql file .

```
str = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME (id,name,con) VALUES ('%d','%s','%s')" %(id,nam,con)
```

Here, "con" refers to the content which contains all kinds of things like single quotes , double quotes and others . So the file became like this :

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (id,name,con) VALUES('1','first','Hi I'm XXX . "435"  'sdfsd' ')
```

Please observer last part of above line, as it contains different quotes, the sql file will not be executed if i use the above format . What is the solution for this ? Will provide more information if necessary .

Thanks

Comment: This type of string formatting ( with `%` ) is too dangerous for sql. SQL injection is easy this way. What if con contains `');delete from table;` ?

Comment: [Who is Bobby Tables?](http://www.bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Even it contains dangerous elements , its not problem here, but the requirement is , it shouldnot give errors . It should work normally .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is sanitize your queries, to avoid having sql injections and having valid queries. In order to do this, you need to escape literal values, like strings. There are libraries for this. In your case, and that's the least safe option, you could use `repr` for strings, which will do the job. There are better options, DON'T USE THIS, use what your database drivers offer you. For example:

If you are using MySQL, you could use `python-mysql` (`MySQLdb`) to escape your strings, so that you can generate sql files which you can execute safely.

```
>>> print a
Hi I'm XXX . "435"  'sdfsd' 
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> encoded_a = MySQLdb.escape_string(a)
>>> print encoded_a
Hi I\'m XXX . \"435\"  \'sdfsd\'
```

When using `MySQLdb.escape_string`, you are sure the characters are safe, then you use the format string you were using. Also, make sure you do this for ALL values, and not only those who are "risky".

If you are not using MySQL, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823735/psycopg2-equivalent-of-mysqldb-escape-string) for postgresql.

If you do not want to use it directly via SQL, look into libraries like MySQLdb for MySQL, etc.

Comment: [Here](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#installation). Check the [README](http://mysql-python.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mysql-python/trunk/MySQLdb/README?revision=650&view=markup). Tell me what OS, and I'll tell you how to install it.

Comment: its ubuntu, and thanks for answer with clear explanation . Thanks to others also . i tried sudo apt-get install python-mysql , installed but import statement didnt work .

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-mysql` should do the job. You're welcome :)

Comment: Did you restart the python interpreter? And also make sure that you write it correctly (it's case-sensitive)

Answer (score 1):

psycopg2 has the method `mogrify` outputting a safe SQL query as string:

```
>>> print cur.mogrify("insert into table_name (id, name, con) values (%s, %s, %s)", ('1','first',"Hi I'm XXX"))

insert into table_name (id, name, con) values (E'1', E'first', E'Hi I''m XXX')
```

Check your DB module for this method.