# Escape input data for postgres

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I writing a python script for inserting of data in my postgres db.

Is in postgres a escape function how I can escape the inserted data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass query parameters as a second argument to `execute`, like:

```
>>> cur.execute(
...     """INSERT INTO some_table (an_int, a_date, a_string)
...         VALUES (%s, %s, %s);""",
...     (10, datetime.date(2005, 11, 18), "O'Reilly"))
```

Then, all of the parameters will be properly escaped.

This is because `psycopg2` follows [Python Database API Specification v2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) and supports safe parameterized queries.

Also see:

- [Parameterized queries with psycopg2 / Python DB-API and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466741/parameterized-queries-with-psycopg2-python-db-api-and-postgresql)
- [psycopg2 equivalent of mysqldb.escape_string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823735/psycopg2-equivalent-of-mysqldb-escape-string)