# Syntax for SQL via python script (Incorrect syntax near ',')

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using SQL server and need to run the following SQL via Python script

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEN(Wav)-CHARINDEX('.', Wav) FROM <>;
```

I have tried to play with the String but couldn’t figure out how to work around the dot character.

```
sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT LEN(Wav)-CHARINDEX({}, Wav) FROM xxx'.format('.')
print(sql)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Any idea how to resolve this

Thank you

Comment: Could you put the exact error you get in your question?

Comment: Also, I would suggest using double quotes: `"SELECT DISTINCT LEN(Wav)-CHARINDEX('.', Wav) FROM <>;"`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'.'` is the string `.`, you want `"'.'"`, the string `'.'`

```py
>>> print("{}".format('.'))
.
>>> print("{}".format("'.'"))
'.'
```

As **@Justin Ezequiel**'s answer notes, do beware of SQL injections here!

Specifically, unfiltered user inputs can *and will* cause an SQL injection where unanticipated commands can be run against the target database by breaking out of the raw string. These can do *anything* your connection has permission to do, such as **retrieving, modifying, or deleting arbitrary data**.

A traditional approach is to use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1582192/4541045)

In Python, you can also use a regex or other test to explicitly error for statements with control characters (`if not re.match(r"^[a-zA-Z\d _+-]+$"), s):raise_`) or [use (trust) an escaping library to do it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104259/how-to-properly-escape-strings-when-manually-building-sql-queries-in-sqlalchemy/25107658) if you must take arbitrary strings.

Comment: Could you clarify what you should do for this particular code? I don't understand your answer at all.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 ahah - I've added an example of the final string being displayed!

Answer (score 2):

Use parameters to avoid [SQL-injection attacks](https://xkcd.com/327/).

```py
sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT LEN(Wav)-CHARINDEX(?, Wav) FROM xxx' # note placeholder (?)
print(sql)
params = ('.',) # tuple

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

Comment: This has a very valuable point about injection and provides a good solution to it, but doesn't really give weight to how dangerous the problem is!