# is there a difference between `quote_ident()` and parametized queries in psycopg2?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

In python3 and postgresql12, is there a safety difference between parametizing SQL queries the "proper" way or just escaping potentially dangerous content using `psycopg2.quote_ident()`?

For example, consider these two options.

*Option 1:*

```py
name = get_unsafe_input_from_web_form()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM students WHERE name = %s;", (name,))
```

*Option 2:*

```py
from psycopg2.extensions import quote_ident

name = get_unsafe_input_from_web_form()
cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM students WHERE name = {quote_ident(name, cursor)};"
```

The [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html?#psycopg2.extensions.quote_ident) is not particularly explicit.  Is Option 2 totally equivalent in terms of safety against injection attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quote_ident() would be the wrong thing to use, as it is for identifiers e.g table, column names. You would want quote_literal() which does not exist in psycopg2.extensions. I would stick with the first option, but using the psycopg2.sql module:

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Safety-wise, both parameterized queries and quote_ident can safely handle untrusted input and will not open you to SQL injection issues. But you can't use quote_ident for values as you're trying to do in your example. The string you're passing to cursor.execute() will end up being (for name `foobar`) `SELECT * FROM students WHERE name = "foobar";`, which will try to find rows where the `name` column is equal to the `foobar` column, not where name is equal to the string `'foobar'`.