# How to combine multiple sqlite queries into one line

Tags: sql, sqlite

Sorry if this question is dumb. i am a beginner and for the past hour i'v been searching the internet for answer and i haven't found one(maybe because i am bad at searching). Anyway, i am writing a query into python so i have to write the entire query into one line but i can't seem to get it right.

```
SELECT students.first, students.middle, students.last, students.birth
FROM students
WHERE students.house = "Gryffindor"
ORDER BY students.last ASC, students.first ASC
```

Comment: Are you just trying to delimit your quotes? If so see this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897020/a-good-way-to-escape-quotes-in-a-database-query-string

Comment: You can create a multiline string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660443/10498828

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two methods:

```
'''SELECT students.first, students.middle, students.last, students.birth
FROM students
WHERE students.house = "Gryffindor"
ORDER BY students.last ASC, students.first ASC'''

"SELECT s.first, s.middle, s.last, s.birth FROM students s WHERE s.house = 'Gryffindor' ORDER BY s.last ASC, s.first ASC"
```

The firsts uses multi-line strings.  The second shortens the query a bit, uses single quotes for the embedded string (the SQL standard delimiter), and puts everything on one line.