# Using PHP variable inside a query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using a query inside [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) as:

```
 $query =  'SELECT * from #__chronoforms_UploadAuthor where text_6 like "%'.$_GET['title'].'%" and text_7 like "%'.$_GET['author'].'%" limit 0,1';
```

Where I am trying to insert a PHP variable instead of 1 in the limit..

```
   $query =  'SELECT * from #__chronoforms_UploadAuthor where text_6 like "%'.$_GET['title'].'%" and text_7 like "%'.$_GET['author'].'%" limit 0,"'.$_GET['limit'].'"';
```

but it shows me an error. There are some errors in keeping `$_GET['limit']`.

Comment: What error does it show to you?

Comment: you need to specify exact error, open PHP error reporting service and if the error caused in query then use echo mysql_error(); and see the real problem.

Comment: The error is Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/ntdg/public_html/joomla/Joomla_1.5.7/components/com_jumi/jumi.php(25) : eval()'d code on line 106

Comment: That's just asking for a SQL injection attack. Look this up, it's very important.

Comment: Ach mein gott. it's even eval'ed! even no SQL injection needed - just run any code you wish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things:

1. The way you're writing out those queries is a bit hard to read. Personally I prefer using a multi-line [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax (as per below), but this isn't strictly required;
2. Any user input should go through [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. **Note:** "user input" includes *anything* that comes from the client including cookies, form fields (normal or hidden), query strings, etc.; and
3. You don't need to quote the second argument to `LIMIT` clause, which is probably the source of your problem, meaning put `LIMIT 0,5` not `LIMIT 0,"5"`.

So try:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']);
$author = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['author']);
$limit = (int)$_GET['limit'];

$query = <<<END
SELECT *
FROM #__chronoforms_UploadAuthor
WHERE text_6 LIKE "$title%" 
AND text_7 LIKE "%$author%"
LIMIT 0,$limit
END;
```

Also, one commentor noted that `%` and `_` should be escaped. That may or may not be true. Many applications allow the user to enter wildcards. If that's the case then you shouldn't escape them. If you must escape them then process them:

```
$title = like_escape($limit);

function like_escape($str) {
    return preg_replace('!(?|\\)((?:\\)*)([%_])!', '$1\$2', $str);
}
```

That somewhat complicated regular expression is trying to stop someone putting in '\%' and getting '\%', which then escape the backslash but not the '%'.

Comment: not "user input" but any string value 
you didn't mention sanitization for the limit parameter
and you are only one who use heredoc for the queries.

Comment: @Col 1. **all** GET/POST parameters are "user input" and 2. I don't understand your point about heredocs. So what if no one else does? It doesn't make me wrong or them right.

Comment: not  GET/POST parameters , but **any string value** goes to the query.

Comment: @stereofrog: LIKE-escaping is somewhat tricky. If you need to support it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106207/escape-sql-like-value-for-postgres-with-psycopg2

Comment: I didn't notice you sanitize $limit in the code. I beg my pardon

Comment: @Col clarification added. Happy yet?

Comment: @stereofrog added wildcard escaping.

Comment: nope :) escaping intentded not for the "user input", but for the query content. Source of input doesn't matter. It can be user or server, form or file. it is not "sanitization" but merely syntax rule. 2-step rule: enclose string contents into quotes and escape special characters in it. As a matter of fact, it has no relation to the user input.

Comment: use prepared statements instead of `mysql_real_escape_string` if you do not know 100 % what you are doing (which seems to be the case for the op). `mysql_real_escapey_string` still can cause problems, when used for uncasted number-values

Answer (score 1):

The hash sign (#) starts a comment in SQL, which looks like your problem

Comment: But the first one works so I'm assuming that can't be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Want bunch of awful answers!

a. To solve the limit problem:

```
$limit = intval($_GET['limit']);
```

and then

```
...LIMIT 0, $limit
```

in the query.

b. To sanitize $_GET['title'], as many mentioned:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']);
```

So the final code must be

```
$limit=intval($_GET['limit']);
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']);
$author = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['author']);
$query = "SELECT * from #__chronoforms_UploadAuthor
          WHERE text_6 like '$title' and text_7 like '%$author%'
          LIMIT 0, $limit";
```

Answer (score 0):

You've enclosed the `$_GET['limit']` in double-quotes, which is the source of the problem.

Try this:

```
$query =  'SELECT * from #__chronoforms_UploadAuthor where text_6 like "%'.$_GET['title'].'%" and text_7 like "%'.$_GET['author'].'%" limit 0,'.$_GET['limit'];
```

Also as Cletus mentions in this answer, there are many, more serious problems you need to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double-quotes around $_GET['limit']. The two numbers that the LIMIT clause takes should not be quoted.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
$query =  'SELECT * from #__chronoforms_UploadAuthor where text_6 like "%'.$_GET['title'].'%" and text_7 like "%'.$_GET['author'].'%" limit 0,'.$_GET['limit'];
```

But you really should filter incoming data...

```
$query =  'SELECT * from #__chronoforms_UploadAuthor where text_6 like "%'.mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']).'%" and text_7 like "%'.mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['author']).'%" limit 0,"'.intval($_GET['limit']).'"';
```

Comment: addslashes is not a suffient method to escape mysql injections, using mysql_real_escape_string will help in that topic.

Comment: `'limit 0,"'.addslashes($_GET['limit']).'"'` still doesn't work either, since the limit can't be a string. It should be `limit 0,'.intval($_GET['limit']).'`