# Node MySQL escape LIKE statement

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

How do escape a MySQL LIKE statement in node-mysql?

Something along the lines of

```
"SELECT * FROM card WHERE name LIKE '%" + connection.escape(req.body.search) + "%'"
```

Results in

```
'SELECT * FROM card WHERE name LIKE \'%\'hello\'%\''
```

Which is a syntax error. If I use the alternative syntax of

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM card WHERE name LIKE '%?%'", req.body.search, function () {});
```

Results in a similar syntax error. I've also tried

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM card WHERE name LIKE ?", '%' + req.body.search + '%', function () {});
```

Which just ends up escaping the '%' sign.

Comment: Third example is correct, what is the exact problem you are seeing? Note that if you want to search for strings that literally contain percent signs that's [trickier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106207/escape-sql-like-value-for-postgres-with-psycopg2/2106443#2106443).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Not sure why it's escaping the `%` in your last example, because that works fine for me:

```
// lifted from my code:
var value = 'ee20e966289cd7';
connection.query('SELECT * from django_session where session_key like ?', '%' + value + '%', ...)

// Result:
[ { session_key: '713ee20e966289cd71b936084a1e613e', ... } ]
```

When I turn on debugging in the driver (pass `debug:true` as argument to `mysql.createConnection`), it doesn't escape the percent sign:

```
{ command: 3,
  sql: 'SELECT * from django_session where session_key like \'%ee20e966289cd7%\'' }
```

(it *does* escape the single quote, but that's for display purposes only)

(using `mysql@2.0.0-alpha8`)

Comment: What if I want to do something like this?  `query = 'SELECT * from Events e where e.Zipcode='+mysql.escape(req.body.near)+" and e.EventName LIKE %"+mysql.escape(req.body.find)+'%';` and then have this passed to query the db? I am getting the same error

Comment: I get an error like this: `Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sometext'%')' at line 1.  I don't understand why it's putting in the extra single quotes!

Answer (score 19):

i've had success with something like

```
"SELECT * FROM card WHERE name LIKE " + connection.escape('%'+req.body.search+'%')
```

Comment: This works. connection.escape works in a weird manner. I was trying to put the % sign around the connection.escape and then get something like %'value'%. That would totally ruin the query. But got this correct now. Thanks to you. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
mysql.format("SELECT * FROM card WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?,  '%')", req.body.search)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

you can always do

```
variable = '%${variable}%'
"SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE ('foo' LIKE ?);", 
[variable], callback =>
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it?

Comment: lets say you have a method called searchUser that gets a name as param and returns the user data or false if the user does not exist                                           
`searchUser(user){
    name = `%${name}%`
    db.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE ?;", [name], (erro, callback))
}`

Comment: The point is to use javascript template strings to have the % operator inside the string that the LIKE uses to search.

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer by editing it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
function search(searchTerm) {

    let replacement = `'%${searchTerm}%'`;

    let sqlStatement = `SELECT * from  clients where firstName LIKE ${replacement}`;

    const [rows, fields, error] = connection.query(sqlStatement);

    return rows;

}
```

Comment: Do not use it. SQL INJECTION.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy way:

```
`SELECT * FROM card WHERE name LIKE ` + connection.escape(`%${req.body.search}%`)
```