# node-mysql - wildcat search in query

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I am building an application that allows users to search for other users by facebookid, email, or fullname and they need only enter a keyword. How do i build the query using connection.query? I use the mysql module. Below is my last try.

```
connection.query("select * from User where fullname like %? or facebook = ? or email = ? limit 50", keyword, function(err, result){
                                             ...
                                              });
```

Comment: maybe it's easier to use an ORM to do this for you? like sequelize?

Comment: find a clue from post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922587/node-mysql-escape-like-statement

Answer (score 0):

you need to send arguments like following

```
connection.query("select * from User where fullname like %? or facebook = ? or email = ? limit 50", keyword,keyword,keyword, function(err, result){
                                             ...
                                              });
```

because you are using '?' three time.hence,making query to take three arguments.