# How to remove quotes in prepared statements for LIKE operator?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am using MySQL alongside an Express Server.

```
    var qstr = "SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE fruitname LIKE '%?%'";

        var q = con.query(qstr,req.query.sq, function(err, result) {

            if (err) {
                res.json({ "status": "error", "code": "DB_ERROR", "time": t });
                console.log(err + '@' + t);
            } else
                res.json(result);
        });
```

Now when I run the query, The actual query is shown as

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE fruitname LIKE '%'banana'%'
```

How do I remove the quotes from the query string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use placeholders in isolation, they won't work if embedded inside of quotes:

```
con.query(
  "SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE fruitname LIKE ?",
 '%' + req.query.sq + '%',
 function() { ...

});
```

This constructs a string like `%banana%` for binding to the `?` placeholder which in effect converts it to `'%banana%'`

Comment: Binding values to placeholders work as prepared statements. Here you are introducing code vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @skiilaa I'm not sure what you're saying here. If this driver supports placeholders, which the default `mysql` one does, then this should be fine.

Comment: You should use `mysql.escape()` to avoid SQL injections. Example value that `sq` could be: `test%; SELECT 1+1; --` (this doesn't do much, but it's possible to execute SQL commands)

Comment: @skiilaa If you're using prepared statements you don't need to escape, and if you do you'll end up double-escaping your values which mangles them. I'm one of the most vocal here about preventing SQL injection bugs, so I'm well aware of what's going on in this code.

Comment: @skiilaa No worries. We all have days like that.

Comment: Or a whole month :)

Answer (score 1):

[Node MySQL escape LIKE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922587/node-mysql-escape-like-statement)

Already answered ^

Can just move it to the second parameter.

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE fruitname LIKE ?', `%${req.query.sq}%`, callback)
```