# Why mysql.escape will parse 'hello' to '\'hello\''

Tags: mysql, node.js, escaping, sql-injection, node-mysql

I will  escape the parameter at first and then concat the sql string when querying.
So when I concat query strings using `like`:

```
const name = mysql.escape(req.info.name)
const sqlString = `select...name like '%${name}%'`
```

It will lead to `select ... where name like '%'hello'%'`,
 but what I want is `select ... where name like '%hello%'`

[image]

[image]

Comment: First check what ``xss(`hello`)`` gives you. Chances are, you don't need `xss` here, because you're not using the value in an HTML context, you're using it in MySQL. That being said, do you not have access to parameterised queries?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol My project needs both query and save sql stirng, i just wrote a filter function to parse all the parameter in every requests,so the filter function needs process xss and sql injection.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. XSS prevention should be the final step before outputting to the visitor's browser. It should not be done pre-emptively.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922587/node-mysql-escape-like-statement

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `mysql.escape` but in this case you would do `mysql.escape('%${name}%')`