# How can I use LIKE in MySQL without removing sanitization?

Tags: mysql, node.js, prepared-statement, sql-like

I'm using the mysql2 package to run my SQL queries and I'm trying to use the `LIKE` syntax. My issue is that I need to add `%%` around the variable, but I can't do that since when I inject the variable it injects with SQL injection proof, therefore won't work. The only way I found to do it is putting the variable directly into the query (can be SQL injected to). I even tried wrapping the string with `%%` but would work either.

```js
WITH SQL INJECTION PROTECTION (WONT RETURN ANYTHING):
await database.execute('SELECT * FROM products WHERE title LIKE %?%', [req.body.query]);

WITHOUT SQL INJECTION PROTECTION (RETURNS):
await database.execute(`SELECT * FROM products WHERE title LIKE %${req.body.query}%`);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node MySQL escape LIKE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922587/node-mysql-escape-like-statement)

Comment: @kmoser That is a bit similar, but doesn't cover how to prevent sql injection. I believe people can find this useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the correct way to do this is to bind the wildcard string to a bare `?` placeholder:

```js
var query = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE title LIKE ?';
await database.execute(query, ['%' + req.body.query + '%']);
```

Comment: Yep, that seemed to work. 
I tried to do it opposite, adding the %% on the client's side. Thanks :)