# SQLAlchemy error: "argument formats can't be mixed" when inputting variables

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have a Python script that runs a pgSQL file through SQLAlchemy's connection.execute function.  Here's the block of code in Python:

```
results = pg_conn.execute(sql_cmd, beg_date = datetime.date(2015,4,1), end_date = datetime.date(2015,4,30))
```

And here's one of the areas where the variable gets inputted in my SQL:

```
WHERE
    (   dv.date >= %(beg_date)s AND
        dv.date <= %(end_date)s)
```

When I run this, I get a cryptic python error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) argument formats can't be mixed
```

…followed by a huge dump of the offending SQL query.  I've run this exact code with the same variable convention before.  Why isn't it working this time?

Answer (score 32):

I encountered a similar issue as Nikhil. I have a query with `LIKE` clauses which worked until I modified it to include a bind variable, at which point I received the following error:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '...': argument formats can't be mixed
```

The solution is not to give up on the LIKE clause. That would be pretty crazy if psycopg2 simply didn't permit LIKE clauses. Rather, we can escape the literal `%` with `%%`. For example, the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE start_date > %(beg_date)s
AND name LIKE 'John%';
```

would need to be modified to:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE start_date > %(beg_date)s
AND name LIKE 'John%%';
```

More details in the pscopg2 docs: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: So if you think that your problem is related to passing `datetime` to `psycopg2`, check if your query deals with `LIKE` statement and `%`s  inside it and apply this solution.

Answer (score 9):

As it turned out, I had used a SQL LIKE operator in the new SQL query, and the % operand was messing with Python's escaping capability.  For instance:

```
    dv.device LIKE 'iPhone%' or
    dv.device LIKE '%Phone'
```

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106207/escape-sql-like-value-for-postgres-with-psycopg2) offered a way to un-escape and re-escape, which I felt would add unnecessary complexity to otherwise simple code.  Instead, I used pgSQL's ability to handle regex to modify the SQL query itself.  This changed the above portion of the query to:

```
        dv.device ~ E'iPhone.*' or
        dv.device ~ E'.*Phone$'
```

So for others: you may need to change your LIKE operators to regex '~' to get it to work.  Just remember that it'll be WAY slower for large queries.  (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres).)

Answer (score 5):

For me it's turn out I have `%` in sql comment

```
    /* Any future change in the testing size will not require 
       a change here... even if we do a 100% test
    */
```

This works fine:

```
    /* Any future change in the testing size will not require 
       a change here... even if we do a 100pct test
    */
```

Comment: It took me 2 hours to reach to this answer and check for comments in my query. :face_palm: