# Python: get escaped SQL string

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlobject

When I have a cursor, I know I can safely execute a query as follows:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.bar = %s", (important_variable,))
```

Is there any way to just get the string safely without executing the query? For example, if `important_variable` is a string, like `"foo 'bar' \"baz"`, I'd want the appropriately escaped one:

```
"SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.bar = "foo \'bar\' \"baz"
```

(or whatever the appropriate escaping is, I'm not even sure).

I'm using psycopg, and sqlobject.

Comment: If `important_variable` is `datetime.date(2000,1,1)` then I think Claudiu wants a function which returns the string `"SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.bar = '2000-1-1'"`

Comment: Actually there is no escaping involved in this case - the driver sends the parametrized statement and the arguments separately. OTOH check [psycopg2.extensions.QuotedString](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html?highlight=escape#psycopg2.extensions.QuotedString) if you're using psycopg2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the mogrify method for cursors -- it will return the string after variable binding and show any quoting it does

```
cur.mogrify("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.bar = %s", ("foo 'bar' \"baz",))
```

Comment: Also note that any approach you find will be connector-specific.  The DB API does not define a standard way to generate escaped SQL strings.  This is appropriate because connectors don't necessarily build up the whole string on the client side; some are capable of sending the query template and the values to the server separately.

Comment: but.. what if i want to transmogrify instead?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us what library or DB you are using, but I think your question is answered here:  [How to quote a string value explicitly (Python DB API/Psycopg2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309945/how-to-quote-a-string-value-explicitly-python-db-api-psycopg2)

Comment: seems to be just what i need!

Answer (score 1):

SQLObject handles escaping/quoting itself, but if you want to use that functionality:

```
from sqlobject.converters import sqlrepr
print(sqlrepr('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.bar = "foo \'bar\' \"baz', 'postgres'))
```

Result:

```
'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.bar = "foo ''bar'' "baz'
```