# How to manually escape SQL literals in Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm attempting to write a very high level query builder specific to my application. I'm currently using psycopg2 which doesn't seem to have a way to escape one literal without it being part of a larger, already written query.

Is there a generic module for doing this? I don't seem to have many (if any) options.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't *need* to escape literals; that's what parameterised statements are for. `psycopg2` supports them for both plannable statements (insert/update/delete/select) and non-plannable statements (create table, create index, ...).

You should *always* be using parameterised statements in preference to directly substituting literals into query strings.

[It looks like psycopg2 exposes some quoting functions too](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html) - particularly `psycopg2.extensions.adapt`.

That said, for modern PostgreSQL it's pretty trivial; you can follow the same rules as for identifiers, just with `'` instead of `"`:

- If there's a zero byte (`\x00`) in the string, truncate the string before the zero byte;
- For every `'` in the string, replace it with `''`; and
- Prepend and append `'`.

That's it. Backslashes have no special meaning, so there's nothing else to escape.

You just need to make sure that `standard_conforming_strings` is enabled (`SELECT current_setting('standard_conforming_strings')` and throw an exception if it isn't, because these rules are completely wrong for old-style strings and `E''` strings.

It'd be very nice to have `escape_literal` and `escape_identifier` functions in `psycopg2`. Consider submitting a patch.

See also:

- [How to quote a string value explicitly (Python DB API/Psycopg2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/309945/398670)
- http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html